# How to acess the appsettings in blazor webassembly

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-client-side

I currentying trying to save the api url in an appsettings.
However, the configuration.Propertiers seems to be empty. I am not sure how to get the setting.
in program.cs:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
   var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
   //string url = builder.Configuration.Properties["APIURL"].ToString();
   foreach (var prop in builder.Configuration.Properties)
      Console.WriteLine($"{prop.Key} : {prop.Value}" );
   //builder.Services.AddSingleton<Service>(new Service(url));
   builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");
   await builder.Build().RunAsync();
}
```

Comment: https://hutchcodes.net/2019/12/blazor-wasm-app-settings/


"There isn’t an easy way to just pass the settings into the client-side Blazor app, so we’ll need the app to request them from the server. We’ll create a ClientAppSettingsController to AppSettingsExample.Server to serve up these settings."

Comment: Useful question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62731756/how-can-i-use-inject-a-service-in-a-normal-c-sharp-class-like-in-blazor-injec  -- applied to the IConfiguration service

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> This answer concerned blazor preview when blazor didn't support appsettings.json in wwwroot folder yet. You should use appsettings.json in wwroot folder now and `WebAssemblyHostBuilder.Configuration`. It also support per environment files (appsettings.{env}.Json).

I solve this issue by using a *settings.json* file store in the app *wwwroot* folder and register a task to get the settings :

**Settings.cs**

```cs
public class Settings
{
    public string ApiUrl { get; set; }
}
```

**wwwroot/settings.json**

```json
{
   "ApiUrl": "https://localhost:51443/api"
}
```

**Progam.cs**

```cs
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

    builder.Services.AddSingleton(async p =>
    {
        var httpClient = p.GetRequiredService<HttpClient>();
        return await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Settings>("settings.json")
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
    });
```

**SampleComponent.razor**

```cs
@inject Task<Settings> getsettingsTask
@inject HttpClient client
...
@code {
    private async Task CallApi()
    {
        var settings = await getsettingsTask();
        var response = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<SomeResult>(settings.ApiUrl);
    }
}
```

This has advantages:

- Doesn't share the server's *appsettings.json* file which can be a security hole
- Configurable per environment

Comment: Thank you very much!
I could get my head around it yesturday.

Comment: As of .NET 5 it's actually called [`GetFromJsonAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.getfromjsonasync?view=net-7.0)

Answer (score 27):

Using ASP.NET Core 6.0 Blazor configuration. Blazor WebAssembly loads configuration from the following app settings files by default:

- wwwroot/appsettings.json.
- wwwroot/appsettings.{ENVIRONMENT}.json, where the {ENVIRONMENT}
  placeholder is the app's [runtime environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Example:

wwwroot/appsettings.json

```
{
  "h1FontSize": "50px"
}
```

Pages/ConfigurationExample.razor

```
@page "/configuration-example"
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@inject IConfiguration Configuration

<h1 style="font-size:@Configuration["h1FontSize"]">
    Configuration example
</h1>
```

> Warning Configuration and settings files in a Blazor WebAssembly app
> are visible to users. Don't store app secrets, credentials, or any
> other sensitive data in the configuration or files of a Blazor
> WebAssembly app.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0

You can also bind the values to a class.

```
public class ClientAppSettings
{
    public string h1FontSize{ get; set; }
}
```

Then add this class as a Singleton in Program.cs:

```
var settings = new ClientAppSettings();
builder.Configuration.Bind(settings);
builder.Services.AddSingleton(settings);
```

Add namespace to `_Imports.razor` and then inject where needed to get settings with autocomplete in Visual Studio:

```
@inject ClientAppSettings ClientAppSettings
```

Comment: Your answer helped me out in a lousy Pluralsight course lab where I could not progress until I read your tip about the appsettings.json file automatically being picked up if resides in wwwroot. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you,  I used your Configuration.Bind to bind a group section from appSettings.json.  I posted the answer below, yet you deserve all the credit!

Answer (score 18):

Inkkiller nailed it.  You can simplify the call into IConfiguration without the APIHelper class and access it directly in Program.cs from the WebAssemblyHostBuilder.

appsettings:

```
{
   "ServerlessBaseURI": "http://localhost:0000/",
}
```

Program.cs:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

    string serverlessBaseURI = builder.Configuration["ServerlessBaseURI"];
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can also just (appsettings.json in wwwroot):

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

        var url = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("ApiConfig:Url");
        builder.Services.AddTransient(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(url) });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the precise answer to the question. In net6 is the same without class Program { ... }

Answer (score 8):

As of now, you can use the `IConfiguration`.

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Services": {
    "apiURL": "https://localhost:11111/"
  }
}
```

.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

public class APIHelper
    {
        private string apiURL;

        public APIHelper(IConfiguration config)
        {
            apiURL = config.GetSection("Services")["apiURL"];
            //Other Stuff
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Blazor WASM `appsettings.json`

If you dont have `appsettings.json` in the `wwwroot` folder then simply:

1. Right click on `wwwroot` folder.
2. Click Add ==> New Item ==> App Settings File

This will add `appsettings.json` to your application. Open the `appsettings.json` file you will see a section in it already for database add a section like I have added `apiinfo`:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=_CHANGE_ME;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },

  "apiinfo":{
    "apiurl": "your api url"
  }

}
```

Now when you want to call this section simply Inject configuration and call it like:

```
@inject Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration config;
```

And to call the `apiurl`:

```
config.GetSection("apiinfo")["apiurl"].ToString()
```

Answer (score 3):

Also in .Net 5 & 6 you can set the value to Static Class.

Example:

wwwroot/appsettings.json

```
 "ServicesUrlOptions": {
   "Url": "https://domain.gr/services" }
```

Static Class

```
public static class ApplicationServicesSettings
{
    public const string ServicesUrl = "ServicesUrlOptions";
    public static ServicesUrlOptions ServicesUrlOptions { get; set; } = new ServicesUrlOptions();
}

public class ServicesUrlOptions
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Finally bind the value at Program.cs

```
 builder.Configuration.GetSection(ApplicationServicesSettings.ServicesUrl).Bind(ApplicationServicesSettings.ServicesUrlOptions);
```

After in project you have access to key by

```
ApplicationServicesSettings.ServicesUrlOptions.Url
```

Answer (score 3):

Building on @Ogglas answer.  I changed the service Configuration.Bind to bind a section of an appSettings.json.

appSettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "myappSettings": {
    "Company": "ACME Sandbox",
    "ApiEndpoint": "https://api.sample.com:50443/",
    "ImageLocation": "\\\\OnPremise.sample.local\\Images",
    "ImageUrl": "https://cdn.somesite.com",
    "Emails": {
      "RequestTo": "team@xxxxxx.com",
      "SubmittedTo": "team@xxxxxxx.com",
    }
  }
}
```

myappSettings.cs

```
public class myappSettings
{
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string ApiEndpoint { get; set; }
    public string ImageLocation { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public appEmails Emails { get; set; }
}

public class appEmails
{
    public string RequestTo { get; set; }
    public string SubmittedTo { get; set; }
}
```

Then register and bind to the section myappSettings: in Program.cs:

```
//Application Settings
var settings = new myappSettings();
builder.Configuration.Bind("myappSettings", settings);
builder.Services.AddSingleton(settings);
```

Then inject and consume in your component:

```
@inject appSettings appSettings;
....
....
@code {
private string EmailTo = "";
    
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    EmailTo = appSettings.Emails.SubmittedTo;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

as an example, I have it implemeneted like this (client-side Blazor):

appsettings.json:

```
{
    "api": "https://www.webapiurl.com/"
    "ForceHTTPS": false
}
```

then, have typed config class

```
 public class APISetting
    {

        public string api { get; set; }

        public bool ForceHTTPS { get; set; }

    }
```

then, load on startup:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton(GetConfiguration());
        }
        public void Configure(IComponentsApplicationBuilder app )
        {
            app.AddComponent<App>("app");
        }

        public APISetting GetConfiguration()
        {
            using (var stream = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("appsettings.json"))
            using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
            {
                return System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<APISetting>(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: My app does not have the startup.cs. 
Everything goes through the program.cs.
agua from mars answer gets around it.

Comment: not related....i wish people would provide a bit of details while downvoting....

Comment: I believe it started to be outdated

Answer (score 0):

create settings class:

```
public class Settings
{
    public string ApiUrl { get; set; }
}
```

create settings.json in wwwroot folder:

```
{
    "ApiUrl": "http://myapiurlhere"
}
```

and in .razor component read it like this:

```
@inject HttpClient Http
...
@code {
    private string WebApuUrl = "";

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var response = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Settings>("settings.json");
        WebApuUrl = response.ApiUrl;
    }
}
```